How to set the watermark with EM_SETCUEBANNER on bunifudropdown with vb.net
I'm Trying to  to set the watermark with EM_SETCUEBANNER on bunifudropdown with vb.net.
I have used combobox successfully but I tried bunifudropdown but it didn't work, is there something wrong with my code?.
Please Guide me
Thanks
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetWaterMark(ComboBox1, "TEST")
        SetWaterMark(BunifuDropdown1, "TEST")
    End Sub
End Class
Public Module TextBoxExtensions
    Private Const ECM_FIRST As UInteger = &H1500

    Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As UInteger = ECM_FIRST + 1 '(TextBox)
    Private Const CB_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1703 '(ComboBox)
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageW")>
    Private Function SendMessageW(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInt32, wParam As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> lParam As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetWaterMark(cb As ComboBox, watermark As String)
        Dim x As IntPtr
        x = CType(0, IntPtr)
        SendMessageW(cb.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, x, watermark)
    End Sub
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetWaterMark(tb As Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuDropdown, watermark As String)

        Dim x As IntPtr
        x = CType(0, IntPtr)

        SendMessageW(tb.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, x, watermark)
    End Sub

End Module

result from code


Those messages are only valid for standard Windows edit controls and comobo boxes. If that custom control does not use either of those internally then those messages won't do anything useful.
